# Creating a customer in the sandbox I always receive a 500. Google Reseller API

Tags: google-reseller-api

I have authenticated my request and I'm trying to create a customer in the sandbox but I always receive a error 500.

This is the request:

```
  self.cred =  OAuth2Credentials(access_token = access_token, client_id = client_id,
                            client_secret = client_secret, refresh_token = refresh_token,
                            token_expiry = None, token_uri ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                            user_agent = None, id_token = None)

  self.client = httplib2.Http()
  self.cred.refresh(self.client)
  self.client = self.cred.authorize(self.client)
  payload = {
      "kind": "reseller#customer",
      "customerId": "example.com",
      "customerDomain": "example.com",
      "postalAddress": {
        "kind": "customers#address",
        "contactName": "John Doe",
        "organizationName": "Example Inc",
        "locality": "Mountain View",
        "region": "California",
        "postalCode": "94043",
        "countryCode": "US",
        "addressLine1": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
        "addressLine2": "Mountain View",
        "addressLine3": "California"
      },
      "phoneNumber": "+1 650-253-0000",
      "alternateEmail": "alternateEmail@google.com"
    }
  paytext = json.dumps(payload)
  da = self.client.request(method = 'POST', uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/apps/reseller/v1sandbox/customers/", body =paytext)
```

This is the error:

({'status': '500', 'content-length': '52', 'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block', 'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff', 'expires': 'Thu, 21 Feb 2013 11:09:51 GMT', 'server': 'GSE', '-content-encoding': 'gzip', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Thu, 21 Feb 2013 11:09:51 GMT', 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'}, '{\n "error": {\n  "code": 500,\n  "message": null\n }\n}\n')

Is there any other way to do this?

Edit:

I've also tried with the discovery:

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
http = httplib2.Http()
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2Credentials
cred =  OAuth2Credentials(access_token = access_token, client_id = client_id,
                                client_secret = client_secret, refresh_token = refresh_token,
                                token_expiry = None, token_uri ="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" ,
                                user_agent = None, id_token = None)
client = httplib2.Http()
cred.refresh(client)
client = cred.authorize(client)
api = build(serviceName='reseller',version='v1sandbox',http=client)
api.customers().insert(body=payload).execute()
```

And there is an error too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your issue is related to this recent bug in the issue tracker.

http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3346

Answer (score 0):

I think they've fixed their bug, though it doesn't appear to be marked as fixed.  We were able to create a sandbox customer with.  Here's the gist in Ruby:

`def self.create
    response = client.execute(
      :api_method => service.customers.insert,
      :body_object => {
        :customerDomain => domain,
        :alternateEmail => alternate_email,
        :postalAddress => {
          :contactName => contact_name,
          :organizationName => organization_name,
          :countryCode => two_letter_country_code,
          :region => region,
          :addressLine1 => street_address,
          :locality => city,
          :postalCode => zip
        }
      },
      :authorization => authorization )
    GoogleCustomer.new(response.data)
  end`

This seems to be the minimum information necessary to create a customer.

This assumes you've already handled the authorization.  One thing to note: if you're using a service account you need to impersonate a user with access to create customers.